# Using $(this) inside jQuery selector with context

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

my javascript looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a:not(.noajax)", $('#header, #content')).live('click', function(event) {
        ajaxCall($(this).attr("href"));
        event.preventDefault();
    });
)};
```

The $(this) selector doesn't seem to get the 'a' object, it works fine however without a selector context. What am I doing wrong here?

---

Looks like jQuery converts selectors with context into :

```
$(context).find(selector)
```

So I think that my $(this) refers to the context rather than the selctor. Any ideas?

Comment: try using `$('header,#content').find('a:not(.noajax)').live(...)`--does that help at all? Something tells me it's scope related.

Comment: Would be helpful to get a small html snippet that could show us what elements you are trying to select.

Comment: or refer to `event.target` instead of `this`

Comment: @Brad Christie Good thought. From docs: "Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span')."

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't get the `<a>`? What *does* it get? And are you sure the handler is firing at all?

Comment: @Brad,Wiseguy: Passing a context parameter has special meaning for `.live()`, though it could be that you need to pass a DOM element. At least that's how the docs show it being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context should be an element or a string, not a jQuery object.  Furthermore, since ids are unique, you only need one context here.

```
$("a:not(.noajax)", '#header').live('click', function(event) {
    ajaxCall($(this).attr("href"));
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**[See a live example.](http://jsfiddle.net/rRqYj/)**

Comment: Do I need to set the context to the parent element of #header and #context if I want live to scope them both?